# Text function first param (_) in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>

$('p.myString').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace('xxx', '');
});
```

the above code work but what is the first param do? a `_`?

Comment: The first parameter is the index. See http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Comment: `_` is a variable name.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) says, the first parameter is the index of the element you are currently processing.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter named `_` usually indicates that this parameter will be ignored and is not used in the function. This is just a convention though, it's still a valid parameter name and nothing prevents you from using this parameter anyway.

What exactly the parameter would be for if it were used depends on the framework - in this case the jQuery text function as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your piece of code the `_` is at the place of `index` which is at the first param in your `.text(fn)`'s **callback** function and second one is the element in the collection:

```js
$('p.myString').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace('xxx', _); // it changes all the "xxx" with their index values
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
<p class="myString">something to remove xxx here within a tag</p>
```

#### *You can see `_` represents the index's of the element as _they appear relative to its parent_.*

Comment: so it's index? why not use index but a _? confusin

Comment: @JohnSt it is just for preference, if you go to the documentation it says index and you can refer it with `i` also but it is just a var of the user's choice that is it.